# How to click on the text node inside a div using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the following HTML:

```
<p class="p-class-name"> 
  Normal Text 1
  <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link Text</a> 
  Normal Text 2
  <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link Text</a>
</p>
```

If I select the `<p>` tag using the class selector `p-class-name` and click on it, the click somehow happens on one of those `<a>` tags inside the `<p>`. I want to be able to click on the `Normal Text 1`. How can I get the text node from the `<p>` tag and click on it?

I have tried the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<IWebElement> GetChildren(this IWebElement element)
{
  return element.FindElements(By.XPath($"child::*"));
}
```

But, this will only return the two `a` tags (excluding the text nodes).

I have noticed that `element.childNodes` in JavaScript returns the text nodes as well. So tried this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var el = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('p-class-name')[1].childNodes[0]");
```

This results in the error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to induce `IJavaScriptExecutor`

```
IWebElement e = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//p[contains(@class,'p-class-name')]"));
var el = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[1];", e);
el.Click();
```

or

```
IWebElement e = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//p[contains(@class,'p-class-name')]"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].childNodes[1].click();", e);
```

Comment: I couldn't get the text node as a web element. It throws an exception when you try to extract a text node as a `WebElement`. Finally I had to do the click inside javascript itself. Thanks for the answer. It helped.

Comment: Did you mean this worked `((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].childNodes[1].click();", e);` ?